# MVC Web Api error 403.14

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am doing an MVC5 Web API Application. I am doing an simple example.

1. Create an Web Asp.Net web Application.
2. Select Empty and API.

Then I add a Api2 Controller called `Home`, and add a Simple Method called `Get()`

Method `Get()` looks like this.

```
public string Get()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

I run the application and complete the URL.

```
http://localhost:56464/Home/Get
```

Got an error

> Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

I test changing `WebApiConfig` adding

```
{action}
```

but I get the same error.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I start the Application `http://localhost:56464/`, I got this error

> Error HTTP 403.14 - Forbidden

I always run the Application from Visual Studio 2013. I did not publish it it IIS

What is missing?

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.

First the web api route template is

```
api/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Note the `api` prefix.

So that would mean that you have to browse to

```
http://localhost:56464/api/Home/Get
```

`http://localhost:56464/` wont work because the route has the `api` prefix. So the forbidden error is default for what ever is hosting at that address.

To be able to use the URL you want in the question you would need to change the route template to match your desired template.